# Am I really supposed to just wander around?

Tags: zelda-majoras-mask-3d

So I found the Moon's Tear and did some other stuff and now the game is just like "walk around! talk to people! kill time!"

Am I really just supposed to waste whatever time I have until the Clock Tower opens? It's boring, and I feel like I should be accomplishing something.

Should I just wander aimlessly? Or are there ways to spend my time more productively?

Answer (score 7):

While it might be a little underwhelming to only be able to walk around Clock Town for the first cycle, these are some of the routes you could pursue in the meantime:

**Collecting rupees**
Rupees are the main currency of Termina so you will need a few for the rest of the game. You can choose to grind some rupees right now while you're stuck in Clock Town. Don't forget to hand over rupees to the [bank](http://zelda.wikia.com/wiki/Clock_Town_Bank), at 200 rupees in the bank you'll get an [adult's wallet](http://zelda.wikia.com/wiki/Adult%27s_Wallet#The_Legend_of_Zelda:_Majora.27s_Mask). The easiest way to grind I found was smashing the grass in North Clock Town over and over by leaving and entering the area.

**[Deku Scrub Playground](http://zelda.wikia.com/wiki/Deku_Scrub_Playground)**
The Deku Scrub Playground is a way to make a few rupees and a heart piece. Since you have to go back 3 times in one cycle to get the heart piece, you might as well do it now you're locked in.

**[Buy a Bomb Bag](http://zelda.wikia.com/wiki/Bomb_Bag#The_Legend_of_Zelda:_Majora.27s_Mask)**

**[Post Office (First Day)](http://zelda.wikia.com/wiki/Post_Office#The_Legend_of_Zelda:_Majora.27s_Mask)**
The postman might be able to give you a heart piece on the first day between 3PM and 12AM, that's if you're able to beat his minigame.

**[???](http://zelda.wikia.com/wiki/%3F%3F%3F)**
If you collect the first [Title Deeds](http://zelda.wikia.com/wiki/Title_Deeds) by exchanging the Moon's Tear, it's possible to get another heart piece at the Stock Pot Inn, every day from midnight till morning.

Comment: Just a little nitpick: you don't get the notebook until after you've reclaimed your original human form, which happens after the first cycle.

Comment: Another nitpick: The Postman's schedule is weird on Day 2 if you don't do another specific sidequest first.  You can try his minigame on day 1 instead.

Comment: Sorry about that

Answer (score 3):

While you can do stuff during the first cycle, Tatl does give you hints at some of the ways of moving time forward.

1. The scarecrow in the basement of the Observatory fast forwards time 12 hours every time you dance with him.
2. Anju's Grandmother in the room at the back of the Stock Pot inn's first floor has a "until next morning" story that will move time forward to the start of the next day.  However, you can only talk to her during the day.

Comment: As a side note, once you have the Ocarina, the Song of Double Time can move time forward to a specific hour in the current day.

Comment: ...or to the start of the next day.  The scarecrow in the basement of the Observatory tells you how to use the Song of Double Time.